Method for minimising mass and maximising surface area of a parachute
I am participating in an Egg drop challenge, I want to design a parachute so that its impact force is less than $20 \, \text{N}$ to ensure the egg's survival. To do so I would need to balance mass and surface area (make surface area maximum and mass minimum).
Initially, since this is constrained, what comes to mind is to use Lagrangian multipliers, however I can't figure out how to define my objective function.

If you want the impact force to be $< 20$ N, you are talking about the force on the egg. Given the mass of the egg, that tells you the max acceleration you want for the egg.
You need to design a carrier that will slow an egg from whatever final velocity the egg arrives at to $0$ without exceeding your design acceleration. From that, you know the distance over which the egg must decelerate. This tells you what your padding must achieve.
So there is a trade off between padding and final velocity. When you settle on a final velocity, you will want to design a parachute that achieves that final velocity when loaded with the egg plus carrier. At this point, you can begin to think about parachute design.
Have you tested an egg by pushing on it with a $20$ N force? If you push with a nail, you will probably get a different outcome than if you push with a sponge.
Or if you have some candidate padding, have you tried pushing on it with various forces to see what the egg can survive?
Here is a thought: Put an egg in a baggie in case the experiment fails. Tape the egg to a pillow. Put the pillow in the foot of a sleeping bag, egg side toward the mouth. Toss the sleeping bag off a building. The idea is that the sleeping bag will act like the feathers on an arrow, keeping it pointed pillow side down. And it will add lots of drag.
